# how to get all values from a select2 multiple after submitting form php?

Tags: php, jquery-select2

After selection of several elements (tasks) inside the select2 multiple, I submit a form and I would like to get in `POST` the data with PHP.
However, I get only the last selected value and can't get the others (`dd($_POST['ovr_tch']);` returns only the last value).

```
<select name="ovr_tch[]" id="field_ovr_tch" class="form-select" multiple style="resize: vertical; width: 100%">
     <option value="" selected disabled>
         Veuillez sélectionner une tâche...
     </option>
     <?php foreach ($tasks as $task) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $task['PK_TACHE_TCH']; ?>">
             <?php echo $task['LB_TACHE_TCH']; ?>
         </option>
     <?php } ?>
</select>
<script>
    $('#field_ovr_tch').select2();
</script>
```

Any help would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have

```
<select name="ovr_tch[]" id="field_ovr_tch" class="form-select" multiple style="resize: vertical; width: 100%">
```

You can access the selected values like this

```
$selectedValues = $_POST['ovr_tch'];
```

Edit: Make sure your `select2` library is properly configured

```
$('#field_ovr_tch').select2({
    multiple: true
});
```

Then loop through `$selectedValues` to access each value

```
foreach ($selectedValues as $selectedValue) {
    // do something with $selectedValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still returns only one value...

Comment: I've added another block of code to make sure `select2` is configured to accept multiple. If issue persists, check form data by inspecting network request in browser developer tool, or using `var_dump($_POST). This will let you know if the form data is being sent correctly and if the issue is with the PHP code or the way the form data is being sent.